# "Timed out waiting for ad response", when trying add admob into my application

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I am trying to add admob banner ads into my Android application, but after I followed all the instructions from Google, and did all the things, I found no ads displayed in application. When I checked LogCat in Eclipse, I found the error below. I am sure that I did edit all the files correctly, because when I tried to test the [sample file](https://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/BannerXMLExample_Play_1.0.zip). I got the same error message.

> 01-04 18:43:52.448: W/Ads(5936): Timed out waiting for ad response.
>
> 01-04 18:43:52.448: I/Ads(5936): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
>
> 01-04 18:43:52.458: W/Ads(5936): Failed to load ad: 2

### Could anyone give me some advice please? Many Thanks!

1st Edited

I have added the adUnitId into my layout file:

```
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label_status"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1183612543061916/9999996585"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />
```

and also, I added test device in my code:

```
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("F84FF00544A8000C28E55068B835F2BD")
        .build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Make sure you don't have adBlock installed!**

I had this issue as well, and since adBlock only blocked on wifi, it started to work again as soon as I turned off wifi and went on mobile instead.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good.

I think the answer is in

> 01-04 18:43:52.448: W/Ads(5936): Timed out waiting for ad response.

It sounds to me like either

- you have a slow connection to the server or
- the ad server is slow to fill your request

Probably the first of those. I think the timeout is about 5 seconds. Any longer than that and it gives up until next time.

Make sure you have a good connection and try again.

Comment: Thanks William! I found that the error occurs only when debug-mod, and when I changed it to the release mod, it works.

Answer (score 0):

It may due to wrong usage of `adUnitId`. Be aware that it is different from publisher ID.

Comment: thanks, Varun. But I think I have entered the correct anUnitId... Could you have a look at my latest edit? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Somehow my wifi network couldn't reach admob. I switched to mobile network and it worked like a charm.